# Netbeans scala plugin - no documentation

Tags: java, scala, netbeans, netbeans-plugins

I have installed Netbeans 6.7.1 with Scala plugin as described [here](http://wiki.netbeans.org/Scala). I got my "Hello World" project to compile and run.

The problem I have now is that there is no documentation available for Scala functions and classes, all I get is `No document found`.

In the Scala Platform Manager I have both sources and javadoc not empty and directories listed there exist. What can be wrong?

Comment: How is the scala plugin aside from documentation? The eclipse plugin is weak.

Comment: I have just started using it, too soon to tell.

Comment: The Scala plugin for IntelliJ IDEA is very good, for the record. Considering JetBrains now offers a free, open source edition of IDEA I think everyone should be using the best IDE around (IMO). Give it a try, you will be pleasantly surprised!

Comment: 0 down vote
 

I have tried different combinations of NB 6.7, 6.9 and 7.0 with Scala 2.7, 2.8 and 2.9. From my experience, the following work nicely: Scala 2.8 (nightly build) with NB 6.8, and Scala 2.8 with NB 7

The other combinations also work but with some tweaks.

Answer (score 1):

If you can upgrade to Netbeans 6.9, you could try http://scala-forum.org/read.php?22,2120,2127#msg-2127 :

> I think the project location has changed several times since the start of the NetBeans plugin which causes a lot of confusion. In addition most documentations, blog entries and articles are out-of-date. I've searched myself for quite some time for a new version of the plugin.
>
> BUT the plugin for [NB 6.9](http://sourceforge.net/projects/erlybird/files/) is available at Sourceforge! Just try it. It works for me with NetBeans 6.9.1 almost without problems. Though there is still plenty of room for improvements as I said.
>
> Marco

Good Luck.